# How is the Dockerfile set up?

Tags: reactjs, docker, continuous-integration, cd, continuous

I'm practicing with docker to create an application with continuous delivery. I can't seem to find a proper definition where the commands are stored.

**This is my docker file:**

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

CMD node index.js

EXPOSE 3000
```

*WORKDIR*: is this the working directory in the Docker container or on my Windows?

*COPY*: this is supposed to copy the application to the working directory, as i read. Fine i get that, but what does it need? Should i define my application here? Which is for example on my D:/ drive

*RUN*: Okay this installs the package dependencies.

*COPY*: Another copy, is this where i copy the path from my application to the container?

*CMD*: As i understand this runs the app, index.js; again should i define the absolute path?

---

### **Summary**

I want to dockerize my react application which is for example in this path: D://storage/application

**This is the filestructure of my React app:**

```
application
  └─ node_modules
      └─ "some files"
  └─ public
      └─ index.html
  └─ src
      └─ index.js
      └─ app.js
  └─ Dockerfile
  └─ package.json
  └─ package-lock.json
```

Now how should I define the Dockerfile in this case? I see all dockerfiles with relative paths, so how can i do this? 
Because the above dockerfile has an error:

> D:\storage\application>docker
>   run -p 3000:3002 dockertest
>
> ```
> module.js:550
> throw err;
> ^ Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
> at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
> ```

---

### Update after Ignacio Millán's solution

> storage\application>docker
>   run -p 3000:3002 dockert
>
> ```
> /app/src/index.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
> ```

Comment: looks like an issue with the code itself. `Cannot find module '/app/index.js'` is an absolute path, docker wont change that. I you are using relative paths properly it should work with docker, since the »only« difference is that your applications' root directory is »somwhere else« within a docker container

Comment: But this D drive isn't my main drive, so how does Docker know it has to run from the D drive and not my C?

Comment: Docker does not run from any drive, it runs containers which are linux based in your case. Additionally it mounts volumes or copies data to those containers, to do that docker needs a »context« which by default is the current directory. I guess you ran `docker build` or `docker run` from your project directory. That is why docker »knows« where all the stuff is.

Answer (score 0):

You run `node index.js` from the `WORKDIR`, so from `/app`. But there is no index.js file in `/app`. It is located in `/app/src`.

Either you change your CMD like so: `CMD node src/index.js` or you start your app via `npm run` or something similar.

Be aware that the filesystem inside your Docker container is isolated from your Windows filesystem. So Docker does not have to know anything about your C:/D: drive on Windows

Comment: So WORKDIR /app is from the Windows filesystem? Because I assumed that command meant to create a directory in the Docker container filesystem. Now where do I add my application from Windows to Docker?

Comment: WORKDIR is the directory in the docker-image from which your CMD is launched. You add your application to docker with your COPY-commands. The left part of each COPY command refers to the location on the Windows filesystem (actually called the build context).

Comment: I tried to run a dockerfile which runs the command: RUN mkdir hello, but after that i couldn't find the folder hello anywhere in my windowssystem. So that's why i assumed it goes straight to docker.

Comment: so this copy command has to be: COPY D:\storage\application\src\index.js ?

Comment: No, you should use relative paths in `COPY`, and you are already doing that. `COPY . /app` will copy everything from `.` the current directory on Windows into `/app` inside the docker image.

Comment: So when I do the command docker run in the folder where the application is stored, it uses the right files and folders automatically?

Comment: Yes, the files and folder _inside_ the docker image. I encourage you to learn a bit more about the key concepts of linux containers :). Notably what is a docker-image and how it is created from the "build-context".

Answer (score 0):

The index.js file is in the src dir, so the CMD should be node src/index.js

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

A better approach is to define a start script in package.json and change cmd to ["npm", "start"], this way the Dockerfile doesn't depend on the file tree.

Comment: I tried to do this but then i got an unexpected token, so this is good because it comes from my code, right? Or is this because i didn't specify it has to be react somewhere? because when i use npm start it runs normally? so its weird it doesn't run from my docker file. Maybe i should define the complete app and define it as CMD["node", "."] ?